# Regex - match a pattern containing two dashes but not three

Tags: regex

I trying to find the correct regex to match the following pattern:

`any_characters--any_characters`

but not this one:

`any_characters---any_characters`

The difference being that the undesired pattern has exactly three subsequent dashes and the desired pattern has exactly two.

Ive tried `(.*)--(.*)` but of course this doesnt work because a dash is matched by the `.*` so the above regex will match anything as long as it has two or more dashes.

Comment: How much chars do you want to get? Which sign is the border? A space?

Comment: there would be no spaces in the test strings but in general, spaces would be border. I would like to match the entire string if it has `--` and none of the string if it has `---`

Comment: something like this?  '.*[^-]--[^-].*'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like already written in a comment, this should do the trick.

```
 '.*[^-]--[^-].*'
```

Comment: This is matching `------------X--Y----------------` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/PtXSIQ/1)

Comment: This matches `x---y--z`

Answer (score 4):

If lookarounds are supported and you want to match words without spaces and the word can not contain --- but must contain -- is

```
(?<!\S)(?!\S*---)\S+--\S+
```

- `(?<!\S)` Assert what is on the left is not a non whitespace char
- `(?!\S*---)` Assert what is on the right is not 3 times ---
- `\S+--\S+` Match 1+ non whitespace chars, -- and again 1+ non whitespace chars

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XTkhpY/1)